# OneSignal customize subscription bell

Tags: push-notification, onesignal

How do i place the subscription bell inside the app ?

[image]

I mean to say, Before login in web app, it must not be shown but after login it should be shown to the user.

My root/login url(not actual) is:

```
 http://www.demo.com/#/login  // here i want to hide the subscription bell.


http://www.demo.com/#/dashboard  // here i want to display the subscription bell.
```